# jQuery Ajax and CodeIgniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery

In this domain http://domain-two.com/test I have a js script that send a data to different domain.

```
var req = $.ajax(
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://domain-one.com/class/function',
    data: {...},
    dataType: 'json'
);

req.fail(function(jqXHR) {
    alert('Error');
});
```

For CI in:

```
function inquiry() {
    $res = array(...);
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($res));
    return;
}
```

The problem is that I was always getting an error of 0.

Comment: Cross domain issue can be resolved by adding `datatype :jsonp` and also `crossDomain : true`

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
var req = $.ajax(
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://domain-one.com/class/function',
    data: {...},
    dataType: 'jsonp'
);
```